# Validate DB Unique constraits

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I wanted to know how to validate fields only ones (multiple).
for example. I have a `Permission` model that has a restriction, in which two fields are unique.

**Permission migration**

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('namespace')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unique(array('namespace', 'name'));
});
```

I know that the `Validator` class has a unique rule, but I think it is only for a field, not two or more.

```
class Permission extends BaseModel {

    protected $table = 'permissions';

    public static $rules = array(
        'name'      => 'required|alpha',
        'namespace' => 'alpha'
    );
}

class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{
    public $errors;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            return $model->validate();
        });
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);

        if($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }

}
```

my question was how to validate these situations, where there is more than one field in the db unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way to validate that. If you look at [Custom Validators](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules)
and the [Uniqueness Validation](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/validator.php#L479-L502), you should be able to come up with a solution suited for your needs.

If you don't need something generic you can take look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16419142/908579).